# Let $f(x)=x^3 - 3x + 1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x)=x^3 - 3x + 1$.

a) Expand $(x+h)^3$.
Would this simply be $x^3 + h^3$?

b. Use the formula $f’(x) =\lim_{h\to 0}\big(f(x+h)-f(x)\big)/h$ to show that the derivative of $f(x)$ is $3x^2-3$.
So, don’t we plug in $x^3 - 3x + 1$ every time we see $f(x)$ in that equation?

c. find the intervals over which the graph of $f$ is increasing and decreasing. State the coordinates of any relative extreme values for the graph of $f$.

for this, do we find the derivative of $f(x)=x^3 - 3x + 1$ which is $3x^2 - 3$ then solve for x and do a chart to find the positive and negative values.

d. Find the intervals over which the graph of $f$ is concave up and concave down. State the coordinates of any points of inflection.

For this, do we take the second derivative and do the same?

Comment: You tell me: Is $(1 + 1)^3$ the same as $1^3 + 1^3$? I would strongly suggest  a review of some algebra properties before attempting to move on to the calculus parts of this problem.

Comment: @T.Bongers Yes.. I believe so. Isn’t it distribution?

Comment: Did you actually compute $(1 + 1)^3$? It's not $2$.

Comment: Freshman's dream https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream

Comment: @T.Bongers I understand a little better now. Going along with the first answer, I got $2x^2 + 2h^2$ is this correct?

Comment: No, it is not correct; compare yours to the expected limit of $3x^2 - 3$.

Comment: One step at a time, slowly:
$$
(x+h)^3=(x+h)[(x+h)(x+h)]=(x+h)[x^2+2hx+h^2]=x^3+2hx^2+xh^2+hx^2+2h^2x+h^3
$$
Note that in general, we *don't* have for all the real numbers $a$ and $b$:
$$
(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3.
$$

Comment: I'm not sure why are the downvotes going crazy in here. Sure, $(x+y)^n = x^n+y^n$ is an abomination we're all tired to see, but aren't we here to help ? OP is showing (a little) work and giving their opinion on the questions. Only checking this site few times a year and I begin to remember why...

Comment: At risk of misbehaving myself (I'm new to the community), sometimes you're just lost and need hand holding for a time or two before you get it. Most of us rode bikes with training wheels first.. This is a basic, standard first semester calculus problem found in every textbook. Regardless of the OP's intent, having a fully worked out solution might be useful to others, especially for self study. But the title of the question does need improvement, to refelct the topic for others to be able to find it.

Comment: Three months here, and part (a), @jhufford, is algebra-precalc.  No one will succeed in calculus, first semester or otherwise, when they don't know basic high-school algebra.  This user has had a lot of hand-holding.  No one learns to ride a bike if the training wheels never come off.

Comment: Not to mention, as a member of this community, you've posted a whopping two posts: one question, and one answer.  So while you admit "I'm new to the community", and hence may not be privy to established expectations of users, especially those who by no definition are categorized as "new users", the aim of this site is to help users become independent learners who can ask well expressed questions.  The aim of this site is not to hand-hold a user who clearly is over their head in their current coursework, nor to serve as remedial tutors trying to put band-aids on wounds that require more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original function: $f(x)=x^3 - 3x + 1$

Part a). Expand $(x+h)^3$. Set aside for now, but we'll come back to it in a minute
$$(x+h)^3 = x^3 +3hx^2 + 3xh^2 + h^3$$

Part b) Use your formula for the derivative and plug in your original function but with $x+h$ or $x$ substituted accordingly 
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ (x+h)^3 - 3(x+h) + 1 - (x^3-3x+1)}{h}$$
Substitute in our value for $(x+h)^3$ that we expanded earlier and distribute coefficients
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ (x^3+3hx^2+3h^2x+h^3)   - 3x - 3h + 1 - x^3 + 3x - 1 }{h}$$
Collect like terms (which ends up canceling out a few of them)
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ 3hx^2+3h^2x+h^3  - 3h  }{h}$$

Factor out an $h$ on the right hand side.
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ h(3x^2+3hx+h^2  - 3)  }{h}$$
The $h$'s cancel on the right hand side, leaving you with
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} (3x^2+3hx+h^2  - 3)  $$
At this point it becomes clear that as $h\to 0$ the right hand side is $3x^2-3$.
As per the definition of the derivative
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = f'(x)$$
We can then conclude that 
$$f'(x) = 3x^2-3$$
Part c). To find the intervals where $f(x)$ is increasing or decreasing we need to find the points where $f'(x)$ changes sign. We solve
$$f'(x) = 0 = 3x^2 -3$$
$$x = \pm 1$$
This gives us 3 intervals
$$(-\infty,-1),(-1,1),(1,\infty) $$
We plug a value from each interval into the derivative to find out if each interval is increasing or decreasing

$$  f'(-2) = 9 \text{, so }(-\infty,-1) \text{is increasing}$$
$$ f'(0) = -3 \text{, so} (-1,1) \text{ is decreasing}$$
$$ f'(2) = 9 \text{, so }(1,\infty)\text{ is increasing}$$
The relative minima and maxima occur where the derivative equals 0, which is at -1 and 1. So find out if $f(x)$ is positive or negative at those two points. Thus we have a relative minimum at $x=1$ and a relative maximum at $x=-1$.

Part d) You are correct, take the 2nd derivative of $f(x)$ 
and find where it's equal to zero. 
$$ f''(x) = 6x  $$
$$f''(x) = 0, x=0$$
So the two concavity intervals are $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$
Finally, plug in a number from each interval to determine if the interval is concave up or down
$$f''(-1) = -6\text{, so }(-\infty,0)\text{ is concave down}$$
$$f''(1) = 6\text{, so }(0,\infty)\text{ is concave up}$$

As always, fire up your preferred math software (I gotta plug scilab here), plot the graphs of $f(x)$,$f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ and all will be clear (I'd add the graphs but I don't know how).

Comment: This is very helpful! I have a question, on part b, towards the end. How did you simplify $3x^2 + 3hx + h^2 -3$ to $3x^2 -3$?

Comment: Do you mean the very last step?  
We have a limit: $$\lim_{h\to 0} (3x^2+3hx+h^2 - 3)$$
You can see that as h goes to 0, the terms $3hx$ and $h^2$ start to get very small, in the limit they go to zero, nulling out those terms leaving $3x^2-3$

Comment: Oh! Right. I understand now, thank you

Comment: @Ella It's worth to remember that if the original function $f(x)$ is a polynomial, then the $h$ on the bottom in the limit should always cancel like they did in this case. This is a small check mid-problem to make sure you're on the right track. It's a good thing that it cancels, because that's what allows us to plug in $h=0$ afterward; we couldn't before since there was an $h$ on the bottom.

Comment: Ella, look up "polynomial multiplication". It's not difficult, but it may be hard to learn by reading a text description of it. I'd recommend finding a youtube video on it. It'll be easier to see someone do the steps. this one seems to be pretty good https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZBhythKVXk

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments we need to begin at the beginning.

$(x+h)^3 = (x+h)(x+h)(x+h)$

Multiplication distributes over addition.

Lets start with one set of multiplications.

$(x+h)^2 = (x+h)(x+h)\\
(x+h)(x+h) = (x+h)x + (x+h)h\\
x\cdot x+h\cdot x  + x\cdot h+h\cdot h\\
(x+h)^2 = x^2 + 2xh + h^2$

Now lets work in the next factor.

$(x+h)^3 = (x+h)^2(x+h)\\
(x^2 + 2xh +h^2)(x+h)\\
(x^2 + 2xh +h^2)(x) +(x^2 + 2xh +h^2)(h)\\
x^3 + 2x^2h +xh^2+x^2h + 2xh^2 +h^3\\
(x+h)^3 = x^3 + 3x^2h + 3xh^2 + h^3$

$f(x+h)$

We plug in $(x+h)$ everywhere we see $x$ in the definition of  $f(x)$

$f(x+h) = (x+h)^3 - 3(x+h) + 1$

I will let you multiply that out using the information above.

Next you will need to work out:

$f(x+h) - f(x) = (x+h)^3 - 3(x+h) + 1 - x^3 + 3x - 1$

c) what you describe is correct.  But without a) b) you can't find $f'(x)$

d) You are going to need, a second derivative!

Using the same processes you applied to $f(x)$ you will apply to $f'(x)$ to find

$\lim_\limits{h\to 0} \frac {f'(x+h) - f'(x)}{h}$

Answer (score 0):

a) $(x+h)^3 = (x+h)(x+h)^2 = ? $

b) $f(x+h) = (x+h)^3-3(x+h)+1$.

Use a) to expand and reduce. Then, compute $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. When $h\to 0$, the expression you'll find should tend to $3x^2-3$.

c) and d) : yes and yes !

Comment: For a) I got $2x^2 + 2h^2$ Is this right?

Comment: No, it is not. Try and expand $(x+h)^2$ using the remarkable identity $(a+b)^2 = a^2+2ab+b^2$. Then, expand $(x+h)(x+h)^2$.

Comment: Okay, $x^3 + 2x^2h^2 + h^3$?

Comment: Still not ! Show me how you expand $(x+h)^2$. Then, show me how you expand $(x+h)(x+h)^2$.

Comment: $(x+h) x^2 + 2xh + h^2$ then $x^32x^2h^2+h^3$

Comment: Your forgot the parenthesis. $(x+h)^3 = (x+h)(x^2+2xh+h^2) = x\times x^2+x\times 2xh + \dots$